# How do embed a record inside another record?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am working through the mongoid documentation, i am trying to figure out how to create a new manager embedded inside a new user

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  embeds_one :manager, class_name: "Manager"
end

class Manager
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  embedded_in :users, class_name: "User"
end

## ------------------------------------------------------------

User.create!(
  first_name: "First1"
  last_name: "Last1"
)
```

but how do I create a new manager since its embedded?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want `embeds_one` association here? Because to me `User` and `Manager` seem to have same attributes and so, they can be contained in single class `User` with an additional column `manager_id` to identify who is the manager of a user:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
end
```

This way you can do:

```
manager = User.create!(first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last')
user = User.create!(first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last', manager: manager)
```

Another possible reason that you don't want a `embeds_one` relation here is that, a manager may be managing more than 1 user. So, it is not possible to embed the same manager document inside different `User` documents. Please correct me if i am wrong.

**Update**

Normally (with your current relations), you can create embedded records as follows:

```
user = User.new(first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last')
user.manager = Manager.new(first_name: 'First', last_name: 'Last')
user.save!
```